# Perlcritic - Two argument "open" error

Tags: perl, perl-critic

I have a script and I am trying to elimate bad practices using perlcritic.

One line I have is as follows:

```
open(my($FREESPCHK), $cmdline ) || &zdie($MSG_PASSTHRU,"Error checking free space of file system.");
```

This gives this error:
 Two-argument "open" used at line xxx, column x.  See page 207 of PBP.  (Severity: 5)

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: What is in `$cmdline` exactly? Is it a file or something else?

Comment: `## no critic`⁠ is all you need to fix this and all the rest of the nattering nabobs of negativity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make Perl Critic shut up, but do no real good at all, just modify the code to:

```
open(my $PIPE_FROM_FREESPCHK, "-|", $cmdline)
    || zdie($MSG_PASSTHRU, "Error checking free space of file system.");
```

Note however that this is **absolutely no better in any regard whatsoever** from the far more obvious:

```
open(my $PIPE_FROM_FREESPCHK, "$cmdline |")
    || zdie($MSG_PASSTHRU, "Error checking free space of file system.");
```

Because you are not separating out your tokens for calling `exec` directly. That would look more like this:

```
open(my $PIPE_FROM_FREESPCHK, "-|", $cmd_name, @cmd_args)
    || zdie($MSG_PASSTHRU, "Error checking free space of file system.");
```

The question is whether you are running a shell command or just exec’ing something.  If your free check is something like `df . 2>/dev/null | awk ....`, then you need the full shell.  If it is just `df`, then you don’t.

Comment: The answer is essentially correct, but in the case of opening a command the `mode` parameter should be `'-|'` for a readable filehandle (you want to read the stdout of a command) or `'|-'` a writable filehandle (you want to write to stdin of a command).

Comment: Not any better ...except when it is. Your so called equivalent doesn't work when the command starts with ">" (which I use rather commonly). That's the whole point of the critique, so talk about missing the point.

Answer (score 25):

If you use the `--verbose 11` flag, you'll get a far more detailed explanation of the error. In this case, the error you get is looks like this:

> Two-argument "open" used at line 6, near 'open FILE, 'somefile';'.
>   InputOutput::ProhibitTwoArgOpen (Severity: 5)
>
> The three-argument form of `open' (introduced in Perl 5.6) prevents
>   subtle bugs that occur when the filename starts with funny characters
>   like '>' or '<'. The IO::File module provides a nice object-oriented
>   interface to filehandles, which I think is more elegant anyway.
>
> ```
>  open( $fh, '>output.txt' );          # not ok
>  open( $fh, q{>}, 'output.txt' );     # ok
>
>  use IO::File;
>  my $fh = IO::File->new( 'output.txt', q{>} ); # even better!
> ```
>
> It's also more explicitly clear to define the input mode of the file, as
>   in the difference between these two:
>
> ```
>   open( $fh, 'foo.txt' );       # BAD: Reader must think what default mode is
>   open( $fh, '<', 'foo.txt' );  # GOOD: Reader can see open mode
> ```
>
> This policy will not complain if the file explicitly states that it is
>   compatible with a version of perl prior to 5.6 via an include statement,
>   e.g. by having `require 5.005' in it.

I found this by reading the [perlcritic](https://metacpan.org/module/perlcritic) documentation.

Comment: I like to use a custom `--verbose FORMAT` which includes `%P`.  This shows me the entire policy name, which allows me to easily get the complete explanation of the error using `perldoc`, via a quick copy'n'paste on my command line: `perldoc Perl::Critic::Policy::InputOutput::ProhibitTwoArgOpen`